# Error with javavfx PrinterJob function on Mac OS

Tags: java, javafx

```
void doprint(Node stage) {
    System.out.println("Creating a printer job...");

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        System.out.println(job.jobStatusProperty().asString());

        boolean printed = job.printPage(stage);
        if (printed) {
            job.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing failed.");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }
}
```

getting the result as follows: 
DONEL
Creating a printer job...
Could not create a printer job.
Creating a printer job...
Could not create a printer job.
Creating a printer job...
Could not create a printer job.

I have also created a virtual printer but still whenever I am calling the button event where i have passed the doprint() method I am getting either nullpointerexceptions or this when I am handling it.

Comment: can you post the exception with stack trace. it might be helpful.

Comment: from what i can see I'd assume that "stage" parameter is possibly the cause of null pointer but a stack trace would be good to provide. can you also show the job.printPage(stage) method ?

Comment: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.Main.doprint(Main.java:763)
 at application.Main.lambda$10(Main.java:461)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
 a

Comment: I am passing a gridPane as the parameter in the method call. all I am getting is a null pointer exception.

Comment: But yeah one more poinT...it is printing one of the results of my database query resultset which is one of the controls i have added to my gridpane which is the name of a patient "DONEL" before showing nullpointerexception.